# What is the problem with this forEach loop? It doesn't run properly

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

```js
let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually'];

storyWords = story.split(' ')


let betterWords = storyWords.filter(function (word) {
  return !unnecessaryWords.includes(word)
})


let reallyCount = 0
let basicallyCount = 0
let veryCount = 0
for (i = 0; i < storyWords.length; i += 1) {
  if (betterWords[i] == 'really') {
    reallyCount += 1}
  if (betterWords[i] == 'basically') {
      basicallyCount += 1}
  if (betterWords[i] == 'very') {
        veryCount += 1}
      }

console.log('Really Count : ', reallyCount)
console.log('Basically Count : ', basicallyCount)
console.log( 'Very Count : ', veryCount)

let sentencesCount = 0
storyWords.forEach(word =>{
  if(word[word.length - 1] === "." || word[word.length - 1] === "!"){
    sentencesCount =+ 1
  }

});
console.log(sentencesCount)
```

> The expected result should be 12 but it shows it as 1.

The sentences count function code has a mistake. Can anyone suggest a way to solve this? The problem is in the last forEach loop. Also I need to question if is there another way to solve this problem.

Comment: there is a mistake at `=+` should be `+=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo in code:

```js
sentencesCount += 1
```

I would suggest to go with increment operator:

```js
sentencesCount++;
```

Comment: Thanks!! I hadn't realized that there was a typo. I thought the method For Each cannot be used this way